# Execute mouseover() from JS without change position of mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have on div, after mouseover it change here content, how I can to execute mouseover without mouse, it is possible?

my div before mouse over:

```
<div id="divId" class="some_css_class" style="visibility: visible;">
<div style="visibility: hidden;">
      <p>Test</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

my div after mouseover:

```
<div id="divId" class="some_css_class" style="visibility: visible;">
    <div style="visibility: visible;">
          <p>Test</p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simulate events using trigger function, but before you trigger the event you have to specify its function

```
    $('#divId').on('mouseover', function(){
        $(this).find('>:first-child').css('visibility','visible');
    });
    // Line below triggers the event programmatically on load 
    $('#divId').trigger('mouseover');
```

Look at this fiddle for more reference
http://jsfiddle.net/Aerious/nLf90cyt/

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's `mouseover()` but I think simulating events is not the good way to go if you need more than just a css effect (like programmaticaly hide a div).

It would be cleaner to have a function that toggles the div state and call it whenever you want to change the state of the div.

Comment: To clarify: $('#divId').mouseover(); // <- will perform any handlers bound to this elements mouseover event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.mouseover()`:

```
$('#divId').mouseover()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .trigger()

```
$('#divId').trigger('mouseover');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use "native" Javascript without JQuery. You could try this:

```
var event = new Event('mouseover');
document.querySelector('#divId').dispatchEvent(event);
```

Give me feedback if it works as you wanted it to work ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger mouseover event using:

`document.getElementById('divId').onmouseover();`

Also you need to bind `callback` function for `mouseover` event on your div with `id='divId'` and change `div` visibility in the callback.

Hope this helps

Comment: The usage of markdown for increased legibility is strongly encouraged on Stack!